# Logrotate doesn't start script

Tags: bash, awk, tcpdump, logrotate

I need to create capture logs from tcpdump. I'm using awk to cut unnecessary text off lines and redirect this output to a file. I also use logrotate to rotate log files.

However, when the script is run manually it works brilliant but it doesn't on its own. Log-rotate kills my tcpdump session as intended but it doesn't start the script. Here is a logrotate config

```
"/var/log/tcpdump/em2.log" {
   daily
   rotate 30
   compress

   prerotate
        killall tcpdump
   endscript

   postrotate
    /logem2.sh & > /dev/null 2>/dev/null || true

  endscript
}
```

And here is a `/logem2.sh`

```
tcpdump -iem2 -p "tcp[tcpflags] & (tcp-syn) !=0" | awk -F 'Flags' '{print $1}' > /var/log/tcpdump/em2.log &
```

It's got 777 permissions.

Comment: Please clarify what "but it doesn't on its own" means. How are you running  (the awk script? it's unclear) in one way and how are you running it in the other?

Comment: when I do logrotate --force /etc/logrotate.d/tcpdump ,it kills all tcpdump sessions and starts the script with tcpdump in the background with new PID

Comment: pawel, that information should be _in the question_. There's an [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42207076/edit) button for your convenience.